# Select top rows from a sqlplus query

Tags: sql, database, plsql, sqlplus, oracle-xe

I have a query

```
select sum(pur.purchase_net_invoice_value), par.party_desc  from purchase pur
join party par
on par.party_id = pur.party_id
group by par.party_desc;
```

which runs fine.

I just want to have **top five rows** of the query and discard the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rownum` pseduocolumn for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT   SUM(pur.purchase_net_invoice_value), par.party_desc
      FROM     purchase pur
      JOIN     party par ON par.party_id = pur.party_id
      GROUP BY par.party_desc
      ORDER BY 1 DESC)
WHERE rownum <= 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ROWNUM Pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)  to limit the number of rows.
Add an `ORDER BY` clause in the sub-query to define which rows to show.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select sum(pur.purchase_net_invoice_value), par.party_desc
    from purchase pur
    join party par on par.party_id = pur.party_id
    group by par.party_desc
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```